# convert the column data to row data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Column_A        Column_B
Akash.Bansal    Deactivate_User
Akash.Bansal    Deactivate_Int_User
```

I want the output as :

```
Akash.Bansal | Deactivate_User |Deactivate_Int_User |Delete_User |Delete_Inter_User|
```

I am able to do one column as row . Can any one help to get above out put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do with this data. Are you looking for a single string, or are you looking for the data from Column_B to be put in columns for each name (Column_A) ?

If so, you could use a PIVOT statement for this (if Column_B options are finite)

```
declare @Example table (
    Column_A nvarchar(20),
    Column_B nvarchar(20)
)

insert into @Example values ('Akash.Bansal','Deactivate_User')
insert into @Example values ('Akash.Bansal','Deactivate_Int_User')
insert into @Example values ('Akash.Bansal','Delete_User ')
insert into @Example values ('Akash.Bansal','Delete_Inter_User')
insert into @Example values ('John.Doe','Deactivate_User')
insert into @Example values ('Jane.Doe','Deactivate_Int_User')
insert into @Example values ('Jane.Doe','Delete_User ')
insert into @Example values ('Jane.Doe','Delete_Inter_User')

select
    *
from
    @Example
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Column_B)
    FOR Column_B IN (Deactivate_User,Deactivate_Int_User,Delete_User,Delete_Inter_User)
) pivotTable
```

This will give  the following resultset:

[image: Resultset1]

You could even, if you wish, make a large string from this if you would need this too:

```
select
    pivotTable.Column_A,
   STUFF(
       COALESCE(' | ' + NULLIF(Deactivate_User, ''), '')  + 
       COALESCE(' | ' + NULLIF(Deactivate_Int_User, ''), '') +
       COALESCE(' | ' + NULLIF(Delete_User, ''), '') +
       COALESCE(' | ' + NULLIF(Delete_Inter_User , ''), ''),
       1, 3, '') AS String
from
    @Example
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Column_B)
    FOR Column_B IN (Deactivate_User,Deactivate_Int_User,Delete_User,Delete_Inter_User)
) pivotTable
```

This would give the following result:

[image: Resultset2]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `STUFF()` function. Try something like this,

```
CREATE TABLE TestUsr(Column_A VARCHAR(50), Column_B VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO TestUsr(Column_A, Column_B) VALUES

('Akash.Bansal', 'Deactivate_User'),
('Akash.Bansal', 'Deactivate_Int_User')

SELECT Column_B FROM
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Column_A ORDER BY Column_A) RN, 
   Column_B = Column_A + ' | ' +
   STUFF((SELECT ' | ' + Column_B
   FROM TestUsr b FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + ' | '
   FROM TestUsr  a
 ) AS E WHERE RN = 1
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9516c/7)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   Column_A ,
                        Column_B
               FROM     ( VALUES ( 'Akash.Bansal', 'Deactivate_User'),
                        ( 'Akash.Bansal', 'Deactivate_Int_User'),
                        ( 'Akash.Bansal', 'Delete_User'),
                        ( 'Akash.Bansal', 'Delete_Inter_User'),
                        ( 'John.Dohn', 'Create'),
                        ( 'John.Dohn', 'Update')

                         ) AS T ( Column_A, Column_B )
             )
    SELECT  A.Column_A ,
            SUBSTRING(( SELECT  ' ' + B.Column_B + ' |'
                        FROM    cte AS B
                        WHERE   A.Column_A = B.Column_A
                      FOR
                        XML PATH('')
                      ), 2, 1000) AS String, 
                      COUNT(*) Cnt
    FROM    cte AS A     
    GROUP BY A.Column_A
```

result

[image]